# Mysql query I want to know visitors who vote for example ( answer_id (767) ) on what else they vote for

Tags: mysql

When visitor votes, I store information `answer_id`, `ip`, etc.

My website visitors vote in multiple polls.

I want to know visitors who vote for example ( answer_id (767) ) on what else they vote for. Based on ip. lets say answer_id=767

Table: **poll_stat**

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`answer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`date` date NOT NULL,
`country` text NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`age` int(11) NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you.

```
select ip, question_id
from poll_stat
where ip in (select ip from poll_stat where answer_id = 767 group by ip)
and answer_id <> 767
```

**edit**

Hmm...you might check that there is an `INDEX` created on the ip column. If that isn't it, perhaps it doesn't like the IN clause. I will rewrite as a join:

```
select ip, question_id
from poll_stat ps1
inner join (select ip from poll_stat where answer_id = 767 group by ip) ps2
on ps1.ip = ps2.ip
where answer_id <> 767
```

Comment: It does not work, cant really tell the reason why cause when I send the request through Phpmyadmin it just takes really long and then php times out.

Comment: it works this is final but it's slow Showing rows 0 - 29 (482 total, Query took 31.3219 sec)




SQL query:
SELECT * 
FROM poll_stat ps1
INNER JOIN (

SELECT ip
FROM poll_stat
WHERE answer_id =723
GROUP BY ip
)ps2 ON ps1.ip = ps2.ip
WHERE answer_id <>723
GROUP BY ps1.answer_id
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Did you check to see if there is an index on the ip column? Run the following `CREATE INDEX ip_index ON poll_stat (ip)` You might want to add one on the `answer_id` column as well. Unless your the server is seriously overburdened, this query should not take that long.